# How to Change color with mouse pressed using processing language

Tags: colors, widget, switch-statement, processing

Hello so for the program i have to create 3 buttons, and as each button is pressed by the mouse the color has to change, i'm very stuck on how do i switch the button to different colors as the mouse is pressed using the processing language, any tips?? this is my code so far!

main program for widget

```
     PFont stdFont;
     final int EVENT_BUTTON1=1;
   final int EVENT_BUTTON2=2;
   final int EVENT_BUTTON3=3;
   final int EVENT_NULL=0;
   Widget widget1, widget2,widget3;
   ArrayList widgetList;


  void setup(){
  stdFont=loadFont("AbadiMT-CondensedLight-48.vlw");
  textFont(stdFont);

 widget1=new Widget(100, 100, 180, 40,
"RED", color(100),
stdFont, EVENT_BUTTON1);
widget2=new Widget(100, 200, 180, 40,
"GREEN", color(100),
stdFont, EVENT_BUTTON2);                          
size(400, 400);
widget3=new Widget(100, 300, 180, 40,
"BLUE", color(100),
stdFont, EVENT_BUTTON2);                          
size(400, 400);


 widgetList = new ArrayList();
widgetList.add(widget1); widgetList.add(widget2); widgetList.add(widget3);

 }

 void draw(){
  for(int i = 0; i<widgetList.size(); i++){
Widget aWidget = (Widget)widgetList.get(i);
aWidget.draw();
  }

  }

void mousePressed(){
 int event;

  for(int i = 0; i<widgetList.size(); i++){
Widget aWidget = (Widget) widgetList.get(i);
   event = aWidget.getEvent(mouseX,mouseY);
   switch(event) {
     case EVENT_BUTTON1:
       println("button 1!");
       break;
     case EVENT_BUTTON2:
       println("button 2!");
       break;

       case EVENT_BUTTON3:
       println("button 3!");
       break;
   }  
 }
}



main widget class

 class Widget {
 int x, y, width, height;
 String label; int event;
   color widgetColor, labelColor;
 PFont widgetFont;

  Widget(int x,int y, int width, int height, String label,
   color widgetColor, PFont widgetFont, int event){
   this.x=x; this.y=y; this.width = width; this.height= height;
   this.label=label; this.event=event; 
  this.widgetColor=widgetColor; this.widgetFont=widgetFont;
   labelColor= color(0);
  }
 void draw(){
  fill(widgetColor);
  rect(x,y,width,height);
  fill(labelColor);
  text(label, x+10, y+height-10);
}
 int getEvent(int mX, int mY){
 if(mX>x && mX < x+width && mY >y && mY <y+height){
    return event;
 }
 return EVENT_NULL;
}
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a homework assignment. A generic answer:

```
class RectangularThing {
  float x, y, w, h;
  color boxColor = 0;
  [...]
  boolean over(float mx, float my) {
    // return "true" if mx/my is inside this rectangle,
    // otherwise return "false"
  }
  void setColor(color c) {
    boxColor = c;
  }
  void draw() {
    stroke(boxColor);
    fill(boxColor);
    rect(x,y,w,h);
  }
}

[...]

ArrayList<RectangularThing> allmythings;

void setup() {
  ...
  allmythings = new ArrayList<RectangularThing>();
  ...
}

void draw() {
  // this kind of looping is the same as
  // "for(int i=0, last=allmythings;i<last;i++) { 
  //    RectangularThing t = allmythings[i];
  //    ..." except that it's less code and easier
  // to read. If you're just iterating without
  // needing the iteration counter, this is nicer.
  for(RectangularThing t: allmythings) {
    t.draw();
  }
} 

void mouseClicked() {
  for(RectangularThing t: allmythings) {
    if(t.over(mouseX,mouseY)) {
      t.setColor(...);
    }
  }
  redraw();
}
```

So: make things responsible for drawing themselves, and give them all the properties they need to do that properly. Then change those properties when you need to based on code or user interactions.